# Rest API different models for POST and GET/PUT

Tags: rest, architecture

I am designing a REST API. As you know there is no real specification for a RESTful API.
In my case i have a simple API where i have users.
I can get users, update them. Something like this:

> GET .../users/12

However for creating users i want the only to allow a subset of the properties.
E.g.
When you get a user, you get many properties like:
Id,
Name,
CreationDate
and so on

When you create a user i only want to allow to POST the Name and nothing else.
Is it allowed to have different models for different http verbs for the same resource in your understanding of a RESTful service?
Or would you expect that a

> POST ../users

can have exactly the same properties as you get when you fetch an existing one?

Or is there something you think i should not do this?
Just wondering after reading many religious discussions ;)

Thank you in advance
best
Laurin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I think there is a good definition of the RESTful architecture style in Roy Fieldings dissertation [Architectural Styles and
the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm).

Second: I think you have a small misunderstanding REST is not about models or controllers it is about resources. Often there is a one-to-one relation between model and resource but it is not required.

Third: To realize your requirements you only need one `user` model. When the API user posts more than your allowed parameters just ignore them and use only the parameters you want to set on your newly created model. Or if you don't want to ignore them return a `400 Bad Request` HTTP status.

Comment: Hi Johannes Thank you for your response! That helped me :)

Comment: What if the client application uses the models directly?  Then there are a lot of unnecessary properties on the object when you are doing a POST...

Comment: Ich think that is not a problem because ignoring a property is easy. 
Why should they use the same models directly it would couple itself to a data model it does not control. If loose coupling is not wanted there is no need for a HTTP API in between two components of one big system.